# FBML Subscribe form

Tags: forms, submit, fbml

I'm trying to create a simple subscription form to a Newsletter, but when I try to submit I get this message: `Unfortunately, your request could not be processed.`

I'm using "FBML Static" app.

Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
{<h1>Subscribe our Newsletter:</h1>

<form action="mailto:myemail@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
</br></br>
Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="Your name" /><br />
E-mail:<br />
<input type="text" name="mail" value="Your email" /><br />

<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [facebook FBML documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

> We are deprecating FBML. On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be
>   supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work.
>   All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application
>   on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins
>   to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

As you can see facebook will no longer be supporting FBML.  Further more your problem is to do with the application "Static FBML" - I do not believe this is a facebook issue.